# jQuery Mobile: AJAX response only embeds first <div data-role="page">

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a small page/app with jQuery Mobile.

The home page (at `/` and `/m/home`) contains a link to `/m/activity`. This one works just fine, the URL hash changes to `#/m/activity` and the right content is shown.

Now `/m/activity` contains **two** `<div>`s with `data-role="page"`. The first `<div>` contains a link with `href="#activity-location-query"` where `activity-location-query` is the `id` of the second `<div>`. The issue I'm running into is that jQuery Mobile does not embed the second `<div>` into the DOM as revealed by the usual developer tools.

The link works fine when going to `/m/activity` directly, but jQuery Mobile tries to request /activity-location-query when clicked on `#/m/activity` because the `<div>` with `id="activity-location-query"` has never been embedded into the DOM.

What I'm trying to accomplish is separating different sections of the app into separate template files and such. However, some of these need additional dialogs (like `#activity-location-query` in `/m/activity`) and I'd like to be able to return those from the server together with the "main" page (I may opt to use `data-rel="dialog"` later).

You can look at the live page at http://www.blitzortung.mobi. I'm using jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.0a4

Comment: Unable to reproduce. In my test a subpage is loaded and there are two divs with both pages from there. They are both visible, which is a problem, but they came to me. Your link is empty.

Comment: I forced the link to go to /m/activity via a real request, not inline AJAX for now. However, the problem still persits when visiting http://www.blitzortung.mobi/#m/activity (page is back up, have been working on it earlier, sorry for that) Thanks!